# Why is there a difference between using a variable and calling the index directly within a loop?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am studying insertion sort, and I noticed that my code only works when I use the variable (num) to compare to the value of `myArray[j]`.

I am confused as to why myarray[i] does not work, since num is set to the value of myarray[i] and because myarray[j] is nested inside of the loop, i's value does not change. So why does the method only work correctly if I use (num) as a comparison?

```
const myArray = [3,1,4,8,2,7,3,23,43,21,46,23,30,49,50,12,44,233,492,32];

const insertionSort = (myArray) => {
    for (let i = 1;i<myArray.length;i++){
        let num = myArray[i];
        j = i-1
        while (j>=0 && myArray[j]>num){
            myArray[j+1] = myArray[j]
            j--
        }
        myArray[j+1] = num
    }
}

// correctly outputs [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 21, 23, 23, 30, 32, 43, 44, 46, 49, 50, 233, 492 ]



const insertionSort = (myArray) => {
    for (let i = 1;i<myArray.length;i++){
        let num = myArray[i];
        j = i-1
        while (j>=0 && myArray[j]>myArray[i]){
            myArray[j+1] = myArray[j]
            j--
        }
        myArray[j+1] = num
    }
}

// incorrectly outputs [ 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 3, 8, 23, 21, 43, 23, 30, 46, 49, 12, 44, 50, 233, 32, 492 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this simple array and lets assume we are using the non working algorithm:

```
 //    i
   [2, 3, 1]
 // j
```

You'd start your insertion sort with `i = 1` and `num = 3`. `array[i]` is also `3` at the beginning. Now as `array[j] (2)` is smaller `3`, we will continue the sorting at the next index.

```
 //       i
   [2, 3, 1]
 //    j
```

Now `i = 2`, `num` is `1` and `array[i]` is `1` too (yet). As `array[i] (1)` is smaller `array[j] (3)`, the right shifting happens:

```
 //       i
 //     >>>
   [2, 3, 3]
 //    j
```

The loop should now continue to `j = 0` as `1` has to be inserted before `2` and `3`, and if we could compare `num (1)` to `array[j] (2)` the inner loop would continue, but as you take `array[i] (3)`, the loop stops:

```
  //       i
    [2, 3, 3]
 //  j
```

than the insertion happens at the wrong position:

```
 //    v
   [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: calling array[i] for this array actually works when you run it though

Comment: @andrew right, I should use an example that actually won't work

Answer (score 0):

In `while (j>=0 && myArray[j]>myArray[i])` during iterations the value of `myArray[i]` changes - but `num` not changes.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at ES6 array prototypes like `.map()`

I have altered your code to use `.map()` and the issue you are having while using `myArray[i]` in the while loop disappears + the code look cleaner in my opinion.

```
const insertionSortEs6 = (array) => {
    array.map((el, index) => {
    j = index - 1

    while (j>=0 && array[j] > array[index]){
      array[j+1] = array[j]
      j--
    }
    array[j+1] = array[index]
  })
  return array
}
```

For some reason your `myArray[i]` mutates during the loop. I tried to highlight the problem with console logs here: https://jsfiddle.net/4mv5x8cb/47/ . I believe it will shed some light on the problem, see the url:

Yet, I am not 100% sure why this mutation occurs, so I would love to hear if someone else doesn't have anything to add on that subject.

Here is the console output screen:
[image: Console output]